# Frost Bite 2 example wanted

Tags: java

I want to make my own Battlefield game, but I can not find any full sourcecodes on Battlefield 3. Can anyone tell me where to find it. I have been looking all over the web to find it.

Answer (score 5):

[Battlefield 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlefield_3) is a [commercial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_software)/[proprietary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprietary_software) game. You are *not* going to find its source code anywhere - and if you did it would be illegal, unless you were working for [EA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_Arts) and assigned to this specific project.

Not to mention that its doubtful that it is written in *Java*, anyway. When it comes to accessing native resources such as the 3D hardware, Java is usually *not* the way to go...

If, on the other hand, you are interested in making a [mod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod_%28video_gaming%29) for the [Frost Bite 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frostbite_%28game_engine%29) engine, it would seem that EA is not in any kind of hurry to release modding tools for the public, so you are probably out of luck there as well...